# Manually rotating a UIView in response to orientation change? (Not AutoRotate)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an OpenGL view that I would like to manually modify and redraw in response to a device orientation change. How can I accomplish this? If I return YES from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:, the system does its stock rotation animation, which I don't want. I just want to get a notification and then adjust my openGL scene to match the new orientation. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification